# TriggerIO - How to change android:versionCode in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, trigger.io

I'm migrating from PhoneGap to TriggerIO, the latest version in PhoneGap was 14.
When I export application, the android:versionCode in AndroidManifest.xml is generated from forge and it is android:versionCode="1372420088", google play store can not publish it because the devices will not update the app with a minor package version.
How can i setup the android:versionCode?

Comment: Can you tell me what `android:versionCode` was for your previously-submitted app?

Comment: The previous code was 14

Comment: Ah, OK - what's the specific error from the Play Store? Can you post a screenshot? All that should be required for proper function there is a  monotonically increasing versionCode...

Comment: I jave removed the old application and uploaded the new, the previous code was 14, the trigger.io code was 13.042341234 something, I just can get it how can trigger.io can edit part of android manifest and can not edit all of it, it must be done in next versions.